# cmd Pinging a specific port and ip

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a simple script on cmd (bat file) to check if couple of remote servers are up and up running

i wanted to ping a specific ip and port.
when i got `%ERRORLEVEL% = 1` i knew there was a problem
and when i got `%ERRORLEVEL% = 0` the server was ok

after some fooling around with ping command i saw that you can't ping a specific port...

then i tried using telnet on my script and telnet dosent return any value (to what i could find) if there is a successful Session or not

if anyone got any other way to check if couple servers are running  for a script i would appreciate the help.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if you are using windows, why don't you use PowerShell.
here is a sample code to ping to a specfic port

```
TNC -ComputerName SQLServer01 -Port 1433
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a fully working Batch file that gives "True" or "False" as result:

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~2" equ "" echo Usage: %0 ComputerName Port & goto :EOF

for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('powershell TNC -ComputerName %~1 -Port %~2') do set "result=%%a"
echo %result%
```

Be aware that this method may take several seconds to give the result...

Answer (score 1):

using powershell:

```
Test-NetConnection ip_address_here -p port_number_here
```

e.g

```
Test-NetConnection 10.0.0.53 -p 3006
```

Answer (score -2):

first you should install telnet client
then press window+r and type cmd 
command prompt open after that put a command telnet remoteIP port